# Stopping Program in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the Jupyter (previously iPython Notebooks) environment, **with Python 3**, and I want a program to terminate early.

Usually in Python, I'd just do a `raise SystemExit` or `sys.exit()`.

However, in the Jupyter environment, **I'm stuck with the ugly message "An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback."** Is there a way in Jupyter to just tell the program to terminate immediately, without error?

Thanks.

Comment: IPython has the option to set a custom exception handler (`get_ipython().set_custom_exc(...)`, [docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.set_custom_exc)). You could define a specific exception type and a handler that prints its message without showing a traceback, I think.

Comment: if you do `exit(0)` and then raise `KeyboardInterrupt` it works

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this same problem. My solution is to use `return` like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Some code
    if something_went_wrong:
        return

    # Carry on if nothing happened.
```

This allows the code to stop without killing the kernel or giving you the ugly stack trace.

Comment: (Four-year-old question at this point. I appreciate the answer, but I can't easily test it.)

That's a decent idea, when you're at the top level. Doesn't seem like it'd work when you're deep in function calls, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the notebook programatically with `nbconvert`, consider setting up a custom Exception (or something like `KeyboardInterrupt`), raising it in the notebook, running the notebook using the nbconvert python api ([ref](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-using-the-python-api-interface)), catching the exception, and not bubbling it.

Example (untested) code:

Notebook `notebook.ipynb`:

```
Cell 1: print("foo")
Cell 2: from main import EarlyReturn; raise EarlyReturn
Cell 3: print("bar")
```

`main.py`:

```
class EarlyReturn(Exception):
    pass


def run_notebook(notebook_filename):
    import nbformat
    from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
    from nbconvert.preprocessors import CellExecutionError

    with open(notebook_filename) as f:
        nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

    ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')
    try:
        ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
    except CellExecutionError as e:
        if e.ename == 'EarlyReturn':
            pass
        else:
            msg = 'Error executing the notebook "%s".\n\n' % notebook_filename
            msg += 'See notebook "%s" for the traceback.\n\n' % "executed_notebook.ipynb"
            print(msg)
            raise

    finally:
        with open('executed_notebook.ipynb', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            nbformat.write(nb, f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_notebook('notebook.ipynb')
```

and run the notebook as: `python3 main.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the web interface, simply hit the interrupt kernel button in the toolbar. This throws a `KeyboardInterrupt` and immediately stops execution of the cell.

Comment: I don't want to stop a runaway program. I want a program to come to an end, if some predefined condition is met. (Say it couldn't find a file, and so I want to just shut things down with a user-friendly error message rather than an exception and stack trace.)